# unoconv dying on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice

I have read other posts regarding upgrading unoconv.

I get the following error when I try to convert PPT to PDF using the command

```
 unoconv -f pdf hold.ppt

 unoconv: RuntimeException during import phase:
 Office probably died. Unsupported URL <file:///var/www/hold.ppt>: ""
```

The version  I have is:

```
unoconv 0.6
Written by Dag Wieers <dag@wieers.com>
Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux2
python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
LibreOffice 4.2
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I have managed to get it working on my dev env which is debian and actually has LibreOffice3.5.

Comment: Bump - has anyone similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Debian 10, try this 2 options:

1. Reinstall or install "libreoffice-writer"
2. Probably you are trying run the command with no X display (tty1, tty2...tty6). In this case must to run libreoffice as service:

`~# soffice --headless --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002;urp;" --nofirststartwizard`

And now run your command

`~# unoconv -f pdf hold.ppt`